# How to render two columns in single column in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 table is defined as

```
<style>
/* Override bootstrp style to make description to wrap info multiple rows in mobile */
.details-propertyvalue {
    white-space:normal !important;
}
</style>

<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>
                        Product information
                    </td>
                    <td class="details-propertyvalue">
```

sdofsdk sdklöfsdklö sdfklösdflök sdfkösdlökdsö sdfösdkf sdfkösdkf sdöfksdfö
sdfksdölf sdfsdlfökö sdfösdlkf sdöfksdöflk sdfösdköfk söfsdköfskdf sdfksdö   
                    
            ... more similar tr elements

In desktop screen in appears properly in two columns.
In mobile it also appear is two columns but description column is very narrow.

How to force it to appear in single column in mobile: first row for title and second row for description so that colum has whole bolile screen width in portrait orientation.

Bootstrap 3 and jquery-ui are used in ASP.NET MVC4 shopping cart.

Comment: Do you want to do this by css without bootstrap?

Comment: No. I want to use Bootstrap 3 as much as possible, ideally without any other custom style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update based on new information:**
You now indicate changing markup is OK, and if the table always / only has two columns, and should appear more-or-less like your example table, then I'd recommend switching to  horizontal description lists: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#horizontal-description

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>...</dt>
    <dd>...</dd>
</dl>
```

**Original Answer:**
This is not possible without using any other custom styles or refactoring your HTML to be completely different.

However, it **is** fairly simple to do with some custom CSS.  Note that your CSS must be loaded *after Bootstrap*, in order to work properly.

Here's a [demo in a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/6w1u11kk/)

The short version of what I've done is:

1. Add a new class `table-responsive`, so that I can specifically create this behavior on ONLY the tables I want this to happen on.
2. Added some override styles (in a media query) to cause the table cells to display as your requested:

Modified HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped table-responsive">
    <!-- your table contents -->
</table>
```

Additional override CSS:

```
/* adjust the 768px below to your desired width */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  table.table-responsive tr {
    display: block;
  }

  table.table-responsive tr td {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Table has only two columns. Is is reasonable to use this or is it better to re-factor html to use bootstrap grid system to create 2 columns in desktop /1 column in mobile responsible layout ?

Comment: See my edits, but sounds like you might want to leverage the Bootstrap horizontal description lists: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#horizontal-description

Comment: Thank you very much. `<dl class="dl-horizontal">` seems best solution. Sorry for unclear question. I changed question title and removed table from it

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem myself. My solution was to change the structure of the HTML, so that instead of using tables, you use DIVs that *behave* like tables:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      Product information
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Rafineerimata Demerara suhkur on ideaalne täiendus kohvile. Demerara rikkalik aroom ja krõmpsuv tekstuur annab küpsistele ja kookidele eriti hea maitse. Toodet võib raputada pudrule või puuviljadele. Rafineerimata Demerara suhkur on minimaalselt töödeldud ning suhkru valmistamisel on tootesse lukustatud looduslikult suhkruroos leiduv melas
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Then you can change them all to `display: block` on mobile:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table, .table-row, .table-cell {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Which will allow you to position them above each other on mobile devices.

I've created a fiddle demonstrating this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/pubzup3a/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'snt it bettor to refactor code to use div and bootstrap grid system instead of table ?

Comment: @Andrus -- If you'd rather have them display with a Bootstrap grid system, that's certainly possible. However, your original question makes use of a table, so I built my answer around that :)

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> No. I want to use Bootstrap 3 as much as possible, ideally without any other custom style

Despite i write my answer maybe it helps someone:

Set a class name for your table for example 'responsive'

```
table.responsive{
  width: 100%;
   }
table.responsive tr { 
   display: flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   width:100%;
}
table.responsive td {
   width: 50%; //Or how much you want

   }
 @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
   table.responsive td{
      width:100%;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Table has only two columns. Is'nt it bettor to re-factor html to use divs with bootstrap grid system instead of table ? If not, how to apply this only to specific tables, not all tables in application ?

Comment: My knowledge about bootstrap is very week. Could we set class name for specific table ?  <table class="a"> and    table.a{... /     table.a tr{.... /    table.a td{.../ and else?